# Blender render multiple regions

Tags: rendering

is there a way to render multiple regions at the same time by selecting different points of the camera view?

I know render region function, but it allows to define only one portion at same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way set the render border to be a different shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168285/is-there-any-way-set-the-render-border-to-be-a-different-shape)

Comment: With holdout shader i can mask some parts of the render but it processes entire image anyway. If entire image is 20000 tiles it will process all of them. I would know if is there a way to render some tiles  for example in the upper left corner then in the center then in another area that I selected. So, if I had errors in some points with wrong materials or modeling, I could correct without re-render the whole image but only little parts to correct and then merge in the compositor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render just part of a final image from Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301/render-just-part-of-a-final-image-from-cycles)